# Is there any Javascript charting library where you can append data?

Tags: javascript, charts

Is there any javascript charting library where you can append data without parsing/redrawing the whole chart?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-click-to-add&theme=default), it's got a number of great features, this among them.

Comment: This came up in my review queue. The problem is not with this answer but with the question; it's is asking for a library recommendation and that type of question is normally closed as off-topic or too broad. This answer is as valid an answer as we might expect to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is a good choice.
After building up a chart variable.
You can just append data through the API.

```
addSeries (Object options, [Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation]) : Series
```

More detailed in it's [Doc](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object)

Answer (score 0):

[LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-installation/) is another great alternative. Once you set up a chart variable, using our fluent API, you can add, delete, or update data points on the chart without having to refresh the whole thing.

It can be as simple as:

```
const pointSeries = chart.addPointSeries()
pointSeries
    .add([
        { x: 5, y: 10 },
        { x: 7.5, y: 20 },
        { x: 10, y: 30 }
        ])
```

Where the add() method can be called multiple times as and when your data needs to be updated.
There are also many customization options (color, style, thickness, etc) which can be updated at runtime.

You can check your input [here](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0005-stepPlot.html) with the result.

For more information you can check out our [interactive examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) as well.

I am a developer for LightningChart, I think you may find this very useful.